# Finding common lines in two files that have some blank lines

Tags: bash, comm

I got two almost identical files, same amount of lines and it's a code.
I'm trying to create a file of the common lines between these two files and also have blank lines where the lines are different.
I tried using `comm`, and it works good but doesn't provide me the blank lines I need on the bad lines, it just eliminates the lines and the common file is shorter(line count).

This is what I tried:

```
comm -1 -2 file1 file2
```

Comment: Could you please show sample Input for same with expected sample output?

Comment: What do you mean by `also have blank lines where the lines are different`?  There are different number of spaces on blank lines?

Answer (score 1):

`comm` needs sorted files.  So, you could use command substitution like this:

```
comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

If you want to skip blank lines (spaces), then:

```
comm -12 <(grep -Ev '^[ ]+$' file1 | sort) <(grep -Ev '^[ ]+$' file2 | sort)
```

To skip blank lines that have spaces or tabs:

```
comm -12 <(grep -Ev $'^[ \t]+$' file1 | sort) <(grep -Ev $'^[ \t]+$' file2 | sort)
```